# Stuck on determining velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

The main question was:

> A car travelled 50 metres in 5 seconds with constant acceleration and initial velocity being zero. What will be the velocity after 15 seconds?

I tried to solve by this way,
$u = 0$ m/s, $t = 5$ s, $s = 50$ m. If $a$ is acceleration then,
$$ s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2\implies a = 4\,\mathrm{ m / s^2}$$

Now I tried an approach to find the velocity 
$$v = u + at = 4 × 15 \text{ m/s} = 60 \text{ m/s}$$

And the other way,
$$v^2 = u^2 + 2as\implies v = 20\text{ m/s}$$

What's the difference between the two ways? Where am I stuck? Two answers should not be different.

Comment: For $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$: do you know $s$?

Comment: s is 50 metres as in the question but the second answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case where you evaluated $v = 20$ m/s,  the value of $s$ ($= 50$ m) you are using is the displacement at the end of $5$ seconds. Thus, it gave you the velocity at $5$ seconds after the car had travelled $50$ metres. That is not equal to the velocity after $15$s, which you correctly evaluated to be $60$ m/s

Comment: We usually remove complete answers to [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/), but I like the conceptual flavor of this answer.

Comment: @rob thanks for the compliment.. I will write brief answers to such questions in future.